# Displaying Google Cloud Speech-to-Text

Tags: javascript, python, google-cloud-platform, audio-streaming, speech-to-text

I'm trying to use Google Cloud Speech-to-Text and so far I've got the python [transcribe_streaming_mic](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/transcribe_streaming_mic.py) code working and it's outputting a live speech transcription into my terminal but how to I get it to output that text live to a website text box like the example on [their front page](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/)?:

I've looked through the documentation for some example code of this but unless I've been blind and not seen it I cant find any website output example code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The demo featured on [Google's Speech-to-Text landing page](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/):

[image: Speech-to-Text]

uses [some JavaScript](https://www.gstatic.com/external_hosted/polymer/v2/webcomponents-lite.js) to handle the uploading of audio files and live recording in order to show off the API:

```
<div class="l-showcase">
  <div class="text-center">
    <p class="text-title">Convert your speech to text right now</p>
    <p class="text-body">Select a language and click "Start Now" to begin recording</p>
  </div>
  <!-- DEMO -->
  <div
      id="streaming_demo_section"
      data-embed="sp-app"
      data-force-polling="true"
      data-polyfill-url="https://www.gstatic.com/external_hosted/polymer/v2/webcomponents-lite.js"
      data-url="https://www.gstatic.com/cloud-site-ux/speech/speech.min.html">
  </div>
</div>
```

Google provides some examples for how to record audio from a browser user in their Web Fundamentals document: [Recording Audio from the User](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-audio/).

You would have to 1) record the user's audio, 2) post the audio to the Speech-To-Text API, and 3) display the response back to the user's browser.

Answer (score 0):

For the Python server part, you can follow this [code](https://github.com/dawntcherian/Google-speech-to-text-python-websocket-server-using-microphone-stream/blob/master/websocket_server.py).
In the client side you have to send audio stream to the server through websocket connection.

For testing the Python server, you can use this [code](https://github.com/dawntcherian/Google-speech-to-text-python-websocket-server-using-microphone-stream/blob/master/websocket_client.py)

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import threading
from six.moves import queue
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import types


IP = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 8000

class Transcoder(object):
    """
    Converts audio chunks to text
    """
    def __init__(self, encoding, rate, language):
        self.buff = queue.Queue()
        self.encoding = encoding
        self.language = language
        self.rate = rate
        self.closed = True
        self.transcript = None

    def start(self):
        """Start up streaming speech call"""
        threading.Thread(target=self.process).start()

    def response_loop(self, responses):
        """
        Pick up the final result of Speech to text conversion
        """
        for response in responses:
            if not response.results:
                continue
            result = response.results[0]
            if not result.alternatives:
                continue
            transcript = result.alternatives[0].transcript
            if result.is_final:
                self.transcript = transcript

    def process(self):
        """
        Audio stream recognition and result parsing
        """
        #You can add speech contexts for better recognition
        cap_speech_context = types.SpeechContext(phrases=["Add your phrases here"])
        client = speech.SpeechClient()
        config = types.RecognitionConfig(
            encoding=self.encoding,
            sample_rate_hertz=self.rate,
            language_code=self.language,
            speech_contexts=[cap_speech_context,],
            model='command_and_search'
        )
        streaming_config = types.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
            config=config,
            interim_results=False,
            single_utterance=False)
        audio_generator = self.stream_generator()
        requests = (types.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=content)
                    for content in audio_generator)

        responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests)
        try:
            self.response_loop(responses)
        except:
            self.start()

    def stream_generator(self):
        while not self.closed:
            chunk = self.buff.get()
            if chunk is None:
                return
            data = [chunk]
            while True:
                try:
                    chunk = self.buff.get(block=False)
                    if chunk is None:
                        return
                    data.append(chunk)
                except queue.Empty:
                    break
            yield b''.join(data)

    def write(self, data):
        """
        Writes data to the buffer
        """
        self.buff.put(data)


async def audio_processor(websocket, path):
    """
    Collects audio from the stream, writes it to buffer and return the output of Google speech to text
    """
    config = await websocket.recv()
    if not isinstance(config, str):
        print("ERROR, no config")
        return
    config = json.loads(config)
    transcoder = Transcoder(
        encoding=config["format"],
        rate=config["rate"],
        language=config["language"]
    )
    transcoder.start()
    while True:
        try:
            data = await websocket.recv()
        except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
            print("Connection closed")
            break
        transcoder.write(data)
        transcoder.closed = False
        if transcoder.transcript:
            print(transcoder.transcript)
            await websocket.send(transcoder.transcript)
            transcoder.transcript = None

start_server = websockets.serve(audio_processor, IP, PORT)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've followed your README but when I enter ws://0.0.0.0:8000/ into my browser it get the error 'This site can’t be reached: ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME'. Do you know how I get the webpage to display on that address after running websocket_server.py and websocket_client.py?

Comment: You don't have to take it in the browser, the transcribed audio message will be printed in the terminal in which you are running  websocket_server.py (The same message is also passed back to the client)

Comment: But my question said I'd already got code that does that, how do I get it to output live onto a website as the audio is being spoken?